# NodeJS SQL Query Timeout Issue

Tags: reactjs, node.js, sql-server

I have a website which fetches records from a SQL Server database based on user input. I am getting SQL timeout issue at the backend. I am not able to troubleshoot the issue.

Below is the full (`server.js`) code which is causing the issue:

```
const express = require('express');
const mssql = require('mssql');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5999;

//SQL Database connection details
const config = {
  user: 'redacted',
  password: 'redacted',
  server: 'redacted',
  database: 'redacted',
  options: {
    encrypt: true,
    enableArithAbort: true,
  },
};

const pool = new mssql.ConnectionPool(config);

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/api/search', async (req, res) => {
  const searchTerm = req.query.term;

  try {
    console.log('Connecting to the database...');
    await pool.connect();
    console.log('Connected to the database.');
    const dbListResult = await pool.request().query('SELECT TOP (1) * FROM [dbo].[TableName1]');
    console.log('Databases:', dbListResult.recordset);

    const result = await pool
      .request()
      .input('searchTerm', mssql.NVarChar(300), `%${searchTerm}%`)
      .query('SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TableName1] WHERE Email LIKE @searchTerm');
       console.log('Query Output:', result.recordset)
      res.json(result.recordset);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error executing query:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  } finally {
    console.log('Closing the database connection.');
    await pool.close();
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

For troubleshooting, I added some `console.log` calls in the code.

The first query successfully executed with the output:

```
const dbListResult = await pool.request().query('SELECT TOP (1) * FROM [dbo].[TableName1]');
    console.log('Databases:', dbListResult.recordset);
```

But this code is causing a timeout error:

```
const result = await pool
      .request()
      .input('searchTerm', mssql.NVarChar(300), `%${searchTerm}%`)
      .query('SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TableName1] WHERE Email LIKE @searchTerm');
       console.log('Query Output:', result.recordset)
      res.json(result.recordset);
```

The error I am getting is this:

> Error executing query: RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms
>
> at /Users/redacted/Desktop/appweb/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/request.js:449:19
> at Array.forEach ()
> at Request.userCallback (/Users/redacted/Desktop/appweb/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/request.js:446:46)
> at Request.callback (/Users/redacted/Desktop/appweb/node_modules/tedious/lib/request.js:239:14)
> at /Users/redacted/Desktop/appweb/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:2662:24
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
> code: 'ETIMEOUT',
> originalError: RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms
> at Connection.requestTimeout (/Users/redacted/Desktop/appweb/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1232:21)
> at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/redacted/Desktop/appweb/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1181:14)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
> code: 'ETIMEOUT'
> },
> number: 'ETIMEOUT',
> lineNumber: undefined,
> state: undefined,
> class: undefined,
> serverName: undefined,
> procName: undefined,
> precedingErrors: []
> }

Comment: Indexing is implemented in the Table. I am able to get the output in less than a second using MSSQL clients. I had tested using client softwares.

Comment: An index will only help you so much with `LIKE '%xyz%'`. How many rows are we talking? And when you say you've tried this with the MySQL client, are you doing the **exact** same query? Same email address, etc.? Fundamentally, the MySQL server is going to take about the same time regardless of whether you're using the MySQL client or code, unless you have radically different connection parameters.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Everything was same while i was troubleshooting. Same query, same email etc.